# iOS: Voice Over doesn't read proper for ".03 hours" text

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a text in either of below formats:

**.03 hours**

**0.03 - 0.05 hours**

In above cases accessibility should read in below format:

**dot zero three hours**

**zero dot zero three (character name) zero dot zero five hours**

But in real scenario it is reading like below:

**three hours**

**zero dot zero three zero dot five hours**

Like i mentioned above the number format is getting from json response as string type and it might be in any format like 0.03 hours, .03 hours, .03 - .05 hours, 4 - 5 hours

to fix the issue, I have tried many solutions like below but no luck

```
hoursLabel.accessibilityAttributedLabel = NSAttributedString(string: hoursLabel.text ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPunctuation: NSNumber(value: true)])
```

Can any one help me out, how to fix this scenario.

In may case it should work in all other units like **.03 (unit)**

Answer (score 2):

> the number format is getting from json response as string type and it might be in any format like 0.03 hours, .03 hours, .03 - .05 hours, 4 - 5 hours

First of all, you should **rearrange the incoming data** so as to **have the same defined format**. Then, you just have to set up this format to be read out as desired by VoiceOver.

Hereunder, an ObjC code snippet from this [complete 'date, time and numbers' explanation](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#date-time-and-numbers):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * hourLabel;
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"0.HH"];

    NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"0.05"];


    _hourLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date
                                                     dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle
                                                     timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSDateComponents * hourComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour
                                                                        fromDate:date];

    _hourLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSDateComponentsFormatter localizedStringFromDateComponents:hourComponents
                                                                                      unitsStyle:NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleSpellOut];
}
@end
```

Unless I misunderstood your need, you should reach your purpose using this rationale.

Comment: In may case it should work for all the units not only for date format like **.03 (unit)**, updated same in question.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula: I answer your initial question that dealt only with hours. Now, if you add other requirements, create another question but, please, don't edit your question by modifying your purpose otherwise it's endless.

Comment: yes i agree with you and thanks for your answer, but i forgot adding units before, only for units creating another question it may consider as duplicate. And your answer not covered **0.03 - 0.05 hours** this scenario. If you have generic solution for this kind of problems can you please update your answer, and it will be helpful for many people, who are looking for this kind of solution.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula: if this new question is considered as duplicate, it means that your question dealing with hours should be marked as accepted here, shouldn't it? ;o) If this answer works for hours, as initially desired, adapt it to your different needs to avoir duplicate questions.

Comment: Here the main issue is voice over is not reading properly .03, 0.03, 0.03 - 0.05 for these kind of decimal number. Please let me know if you have any solution for this. Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula: see the sheet 'Numbers' in the provided explanation link for these numbers to be read out by VoiceOver as decimal numbers ⟹ the example may be the solution.

Comment: yes got it, Thank you. But may i know the solution for these scenarios like 3 - 5, 0.03 - 0.05, 0.03, .03, 3. Here my main problem is as i mentioned json response is in string format. So suppose in this scenario 3 - 5 i have to split this to invidiual elemnts and apply NumberFormatter then have to combine individual accessibility elements(Am i correct? Please correct me if i am wrong) or do we have any other solution.

Comment: You're right and, with the low details I know, here's what I would do: 1. rip your numbers out of the JSON response, 2. apply and adapt the code snippets provided in the link (date, time and numbers) for each one of them. The provided website is very rich in a11y information of all kinds: don't hesitate to return from time to time as a breviary.